# pandas column names string manipulation

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a Pandas df with long string heavy column names, I want some numbers and a string out of the column name:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]],
columns=['Base + Trial Spot Price(X220) Settle Price S=1 [1.00] 1932', 'Base + Trial Spot Price(Y220) Settle Price S=1 [1.00] 2012', 'Base + Trial Spot Price(Y220) Settle Price S=1 [1.00] 2015'])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDvgV.png)

I want to strip certain values out of the column name and add them as a column level.

So I would end up with:

```
X220, Y220, Y220
1932, 2012, 2015
```

as the multilevel columns.

I have tried split/strip inside list/dict comprehension but couldn't figure out how to chain these approaches (like you can chain replace in pandas). I played around with regex but I didn't get far.

Thanks

Comment: Is it always `'Base + Trial Spot Price({thing you want}) Settle Price S=1 [1.00] {the year you want}'`?

Comment: Yes, spot on @Chinny84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use str.extract to extract the desired values for the column names and then multiindex.from_tuples for creating multi-index

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract('.*?\((.*)\).*?(\d{4})', expand=True)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)
```

You get

```
    X220            Y220
    1932    2012    2015
0   1       3       5
1   2       4       6
```

Comment: Thanks, looks great, are you able to explain the regex in simple terms?

Comment: This regex captures two groups, first group with values inside parenthesis \(()\) and second one captures the year at the end, \d{4} ensures that it only captures year in the 4 digit format and not any other numbers which are not valid. It is much more robust than splitting a string as even one difference of space somewhere and the whole solution will go haywire.

Answer (score 0):

You can create tuples from the extract column data and pass it to the function, `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples()` this will generate the columns, then you can recreate the dataframe. Please find below the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.multi_sparse', False)

values = [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(values,columns=['Base + Trial Spot Price(X220) Settle Price S=1 [1.00] 1932', 'Base + Trial Spot Price(Y220) Settle Price S=1 [1.00] 2012', 'Base + Trial Spot Price(Y220) Settle Price S=1 [1.00] 2015'])


cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(df.columns[0][24:28], df.columns[0][54:]), (df.columns[1][24:28], df.columns[0][54:]), (df.columns[2][24:28], df.columns[0][54:])])
pd.DataFrame(values, columns=cols)
```

**Output:**

```
    X220    Y220    Y220
    1932    1932    1932
0   1   3   5
1   2   4   6
```

The line `pd.set_option('display.multi_sparse', False)` is used to configure the multiaxis to have repeating column names.

**References:**

1. [MultiIndex / Advanced Indexing — pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)